# How to Add an Interval to a Date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get a new date from the product of 'date' + 'time interval'.

Something like this.

> '15/02/2016 18:00:00' + '+00 02:00:00.000000'

Expected result:

> '15/02/2016 20:00:00'

But using the columns in database.

```
CREATE TABLE timerest 
(
      DATE_ASIGN         DATE,   
      TIME_ASIGN         INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(0) 
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is the second column a varchar holding formatted text? Or an oracle INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatype?

Comment: Hello, the second colum is INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: The bare minimum code you should share is the `CREATE TABLE` statement. People can be very creative when misusing date related types.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález updated

Comment: `date_assign + time_assign` should work. How are you adding those values and what is the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add them together:

```
insert into timerest (date_asign, time_asign)
values (to_date('15/02/2016 18:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
  to_dsinterval('+00 02:00:00.000000'));

alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
select date_asign + time_asign from timerest;

DATE_ASIGN+TIME_ASIGN
---------------------
15/02/2016 20:00:00
```

This follows the rules for [datetime/interval arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208): date + interval = date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date in DATE format you can simply add the a numeric interval that represents days (for example 1.5 is 1 day and a half)

You can extract from the time interval days and hours and then add them to to you date because, if I remember correctly, you can't add directly them to a date type (maybe to a timestamp type you can)

To extract the days you can use the extract function:
(
extract(second from TIME_ASIGN)/3600)+(extract(hour from TIME_ASIGN)/24)+(extract(day from TIME_ASIGN)/24)

then you add the number to your DATE_ASIGN